# tts for android application

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i have created an android application which is working well before adding the audio interface to it. For the tts tutorial i have followed [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html)

The tutorial code is working fine. but when i use it in my code i am getting `Null pointer exception at tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);` line . please help me out to sort out this problem.and i am sure that problem is not with the string s, i have checked it.

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Handler mhandler = new Handler();

    Button mybtn[] = new Button[12];

    Button select_btn, home_btn;

    EditText et;

    Bundle b;

    int var = 0;

    private int MY_DATA_CHECKCODE = 0;

    private TextToSpeech tts;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        select_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        home_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
        et.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        b = new Bundle();

        for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
            String btnid = "btn" + i;
            int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id",
                    getPackageName());
            mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
        }

        mybtn[var].requestFocus();
        Intent checkin = new Intent();
        checkin.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkin, MY_DATA_CHECKCODE);

        select_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                Button bt;
                bt = (Button) getCurrentFocus();

                if (bt.equals(mybtn[10])) {
                    String s = et.getText().toString();
                    int l = s.length();

                    if (l > 0) {
                        String t;
                        if (l > 1)
                            t = s.substring(0, l - 1);
                        else
                            t = "";

                        et.setText(t, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    }

                }

                else if (bt.equals(mybtn[11])) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(TimerActivity.this, Calling.class);
                    String s = et.getText().toString().trim();
                    b.putString("number", s);
                    in.putExtras(b);
                    if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
                        tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    }

                    // else say enter a valid number
                }
                // CharSequence cs= bt.getText();
                // if(cs.equals(0))
                // et.setText("121");
                // else
                // if(!(bt.equals(0)))
                else
                    et.setText(et.getText() + "" + bt.getText(),
                            TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                // else
                // et.setText("google",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });

        home_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                finish();
            }
        });

        final Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // final long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
                // mhandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                // et.setText("i am the man");

                mybtn[var].requestFocus();
                String s = mybtn[var].getText().toString();
                s = "abcd";
                if (s != null && s.length() > 0)
                    tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                var = (var + 1) % 12;
                // mybtn[var].requestFocus();

                mhandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);

            }
        };

        mhandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECKCODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            } else {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(TimerActivity.this,
                    "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(TimerActivity.this,
                    "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check tts? Possibly the initialization in onActivityResult() is not yet completed and tts is still null.

Comment: i have used tts=null in the beginning and tried to check whether it is  null by using tts.equals(0). but it is returning NUll pointer exception during that checking as well. what could be the fix for this.

Comment: To check if tts is null do not use tts.equals(0). First null and 0 are different objects (and types!) and second if tts is null you cannot call equals() on it. Use this expression: tts == null
But your experiment suggests that tts is null!

Comment: thnaks dude.what u said is correct yaar, after checking the tts!=null it is working ,but still one more glitch. Can i delay that focus change option till the time tts gets initialized? how to do it.

Comment: Dude one more doubt,still i have used the finish() to kill my applicaiton it is still running. what is the solution to permanently kill my applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

Before you call finish(), you need to call tts.shutdown() to tell Android you're not using it any more. You should probably call in onDestroy(). Doing this will stop the speaker once the application is closed.